# Configuring Maven in Eclipse to work with Java source level 7

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have the following problem while trying to execute the compile goal on an Eclipse Java project with Maven:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project ...: Compilation failure
>
> [ERROR] multi-catch statement is not supported in -source 1.5
>
> [ERROR] (use -source 7 or higher to enable multi-catch statement)

The JDK in the Eclipse project is configured to use version 1.8.0_60.

The compiler compliance level is also set to 1.8: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SvsU3.jpg

However, the settings above are related to the Eclipse project configuration and not to Maven settings.

In Window -> Preferences, I have seen the compiler plugin is also set to 1.8: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6saSz.jpg

The question is: how to I tell Maven to use source 1.7 (or above)?

Comment: Just type 'maven set java version'  in any search engine ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding the following to pom.xml

```
<properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the used JDK/JRE on the project java build path and compiler settings, but it is important that you click on:

```
maven->update project
```

before the change will take effect.